# Rearranging and deduplicating SQL columns based on column data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry I know that's a rubbish Title but I couldn't think of a more concise way of describing the issue.

I have a (MSSQL 2008) table that contains telephone numbers:

```
 | CustomerID | Tel1     | Tel2      | Tel3     | Tel4     | Tel5      | Tel6   |
 | Cust001    | 01222222 | 012333333 | 07111111 | 07222222 | 01222222  | NULL   |
 | Cust002    | 07444444 | 015333333 | 07555555 | 07555555 | NULL      | NULL   |
 | Cust003    | 01333333 | 017777777 | 07888888 | 07011111 | 016666666 | 013333 |
```

I'd like to:

- Remove any duplicate phone numbers
- Rearrange the telephone numbers so that anything beginning with "07" is the first phone number. If there are multiple 07's, they should be in the first fields. The order of the numbers apart from that doesn't really matter.

So, for example, after processing, the table would look like:

```
 | CustomerID | Tel1     | Tel2      | Tel3      | Tel4      | Tel5     | Tel6      |
 | Cust001    | 07111111 | 07222222  | 01222222  | 012333333 | NULL     | NULL      |
 | Cust002    | 07444444 | 07555555  | 015333333 | NULL      | NULL     | NULL      |
 | Cust003    | 07888888 | 07011111  | 016666666 | 013333    | 01333333 | 017777777 |
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to efficiently achieve my goal (there are 600,000+ records in the table). Can anyone help?

I've created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c4d1/9) if it'll help anyone play around with the scenario.

Comment: Would it be easier to have a row per phone number rather than columns?

Comment: Undoubtedly, but I'm stuck with this table design :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break up the numbers into individual rows using UNPIVOT, then reorder them based on the occurence of the '07' prefix using ROW_NUMBER(), and finally recombine it using PIVOT to end up with the 6 `Tel` columns again.

```
select *
  FROM
  (
    select CustomerID, Col, Tel
      FROM
      (
        select *, Col='Tel' + RIGHT(
               row_number() over (partition by CustomerID
                                  order by case
                                         when Tel like '07%' then 1
                                         else 2
                                         end),10)
         from phonenumbers
         UNPIVOT (Tel for Seq in (Tel1,Tel2,Tel3,Tel4,Tel5,Tel6)) seqs
      ) U
  ) P
  PIVOT (MAX(TEL) for Col IN (Tel1,Tel2,Tel3,Tel4,Tel5,Tel6)) V;
```

### SQL Fiddle

Comment: Brilliant! However, this still seems to give me duplicates. Is there any way of building deduplication into the process, or should I look to do that as separate code?

Comment: Have you checked the SQL Fiddle? Your original one had CustomerIDs repeated

Comment: Yes I spotted that far too late :( I've corrected it now and added in your code.

Comment: ✓ for the rearranging part - I'll ask about deduplication as a seperate question. Thank you *very* much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps using cursor to collect all customer id and sorting the fields...traditional sorting technique as we used to do in school c++ ..lolz...like to know if any other method possible.

If you dont get any then it is the last way . It will take a long time for sure to execute.