# Deduplicating SQL data per row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Following on from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784525/rearranging-and-deduplicating-sql-columns-based-on-column-data), I'm trying to tidy up a SQL table containing phone numbers. I need to remove duplicate numbers *per row* - not across the whole table. For example, my table looks like:

```
 | CustomerID | Tel1     | Tel2      | Tel3     | Tel4      | Tel5      | Tel6     |
 | Cust001    | 01222222 | 012333333 | 07111111 | 07222222  | 01222222  | NULL     |
 | Cust002    | 07444444 | 07555555  | 015333333| 07555555  | NULL      | NULL     |
 | Cust003    | 01222222 | 017777777 | 07888888 | 017777777 | 016666666 | 01222222 |
```

and I'd like to remove any number that appears twice or more in the same row... so the table would end up looking like:

```
 | CustomerID | Tel1     | Tel2      | Tel3     | Tel4     | Tel5      | Tel6   |
 | Cust001    | 01222222 | 012333333 | 07111111 | 07222222 | NULL      | NULL   |
 | Cust002    | 07444444 | 015333333 | 07555555 | NULL     | NULL      | NULL   |
 | Cust003    | 01222222 | 017777777 | 07888888 | 016666666| 013333    | NULL   |
```

The order of the phone numbers isn't important, as long as the numbers are in the first columns and any NULLS are to "the right".

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c4d1/21) is here - can anyone suggest how to efficiently remove duplicate values per row?

Comment: **Side note:** Try to normalize your table so that you have one more table `CustomersPhones`: `CustomerId` foreign key to the customers table, `PhoneNumber`

Comment: As another side note, if you follow the advice above, you could use simple unique constraints to ensure that you didn't store duplicate phone numbers for customers as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I've inherited this table structure, as horrible as it is, and changing it isn't feasible :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try strait-forward approach, especially if it's a one-time thing or do you your clean-up occasionally.

```
UPDATE phonenumbers SET tel6 = NULL
 WHERE tel6 IN(tel5,tel4, tel3, tel2, tel1);
UPDATE phonenumbers SET tel5 = NULL
 WHERE tel5 IN(tel4, tel3, tel2, tel1);
UPDATE phonenumbers SET tel4 = NULL
 WHERE tel4 IN(tel3, tel2, tel1);
UPDATE phonenumbers SET tel3 = NULL
 WHERE tel3 IN(tel2, tel1);
UPDATE phonenumbers SET tel2 = NULL
 WHERE tel2 = tel1;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81bce/1)**

*Nevertheless, I totally agree with @Mahmoud Gamal and @steoleary that if you can change DDL of your table you should do it.*

Comment: It's a big table that needs regularly cleansed, but this seems the most sensible option to me - thank you!

Comment: You are certainly welcome. Wrap it up into a stored procedure and run it with SQL Agent in off hours.